# Building an HTML5 audio streaming Chrome extension - how to stop buffering the stream

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

The extension is a simple browser action. When pressed, it toggles the audio on/off.

My ideal workflow is to press the button and it will turn on; press it again and it will turn off; and press it a third time and it will start at the present time (not at the previously paused time).

From my research, HTML5 audio streaming does not have a function to stop buffering like audio.stop().

Is there a way to hack around this? Can I simply turn off or close the background window streaming the audio, and reload it when I need to? I feel like this will also make the extension much more light weight.

Here is my code (this code is functional, but it pauses and resumes at the same times):

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "kcpr",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
  "notifications"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "icon.png"
],

"background": {
  "page": "music.html",
  "persistent": false
},

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png"   
}
}
```

**music.html**

```
<audio id="stream" controls="" autoplay="" preload="none" name="media">
<source src="http://129.65.35.106:8000/KCPRMP3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<script type="text/javascript" src="music.js"></script>
```

**music.js**

```
var playing = false;
var stream = document.getElementById("stream");  
stream.pause();

function doSomething() {   
    var startNotification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
        'icon.png',
        'starting',
        'Starting!!'
    );
    var stopNotification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
        'icon.png',
        'stopping',
        'Stopping!!!'
    );             
    if (playing == false) {
        startNotification.show();
        setTimeout(function(){ startNotification.cancel(); },1500);
        stream.play(); 
        playing = true;
    }
    else {
        stopNotification.show();
        setTimeout(function(){ stopNotification.cancel(); },1500);
        stream.pause();                
        playing = false;
    }
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stream.src = '';
stream.src = null;
```

Or you could try setting it to a "blank" mp3 dataURI. The above should work though.

Comment: That helped me a lot, so thank you. However, every time I load the page a second time, I feel like there is a huge performance drop. Looking at Chrome's network tab, I can see "CAUTION: request is not finished yet!" on the streaming request.

Comment: @lucasdavid Might be worth asking a new question. This question (and answer) is from '13